# how to write view with multi relationships model in Django

Tags: django, view, relationship

to make it simple lets assume we have a **employer,employee and job** relationship.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Employer(models.Model):
    employer_user = models.ForeignKey(User) #Employer user_id

class Employee(models.Model):
    employee_user = models.ForeignKey(User) #Employee user_id

class Job(models.Model):
    employer = models.ForeignKey(Employer)
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

i have a database table that saves each job with columns (employer_id,employee_id,job_title)

when employer puts request (job_title) by his account(Employer.user.id) django(based on determined method select_employee) must select **one online employee** and **request him for job** and **waits for answer** if accepted save it in database if rejected another employee is determined and the the same as previous waits for answer and so on and if no other employee an error should send.

(i have my procedure to determine employee) 
how can implement it.
**my main problems is Serializers and View classes.**

Comment: Isn't this what you are looking for? http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/

Comment: Thanks, Chirdeep Tomar. that was about Serializer Relations though that helps but is not my answer i updated question and make it more detailed